# Existence of a Lorentzian manifold

Tags: riemannian-geometry, semi-riemannian-geometry

Does there exist a smooth compact Lorentzian manifold $M^n$ with n > 2, that has constant curvature, is simply connected and has Euler number (Euler characteristic) $\chi(M)=0$?

Comment: This seems like a very precise question. What is your motivation for asking?

Comment: In Bruno Klinglers proof of geodesic completeness of compact Lorentzian manifolds with constant sectional curvature he studies the universal covering space $\tilde{M}$ of $M$ and assumes it has infinite deck group. This happens if and only if $\tilde{M}$ is non-compact. $\tilde{M}$ has to be simply connected, have constant curvature, Lorentzian index and by O'neills book on semi-riemannian geometry existence of a Lorentzian metric is equivalent to either non-compactness or compactness + $\chi(\tilde{M})=0$. 

Does the answer lie in a simple non-existence assertion?

Comment: Come to think about it, I am a bit confused about the Euler characteristic as well. Isn't this only defined for surfaces?